# How to pass selected single choice option to specific text field

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog

How can a selected option from a single choice menu be passed to a different composable to that it is displayed in a `Text` object? Would I need to modify the `selectedOption` value in some way?

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSettings(navController: NavController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {...},
        content = {
            LazyColumn(...) {
                item {
                    ComposableSettingTheme()
                }
            }
        },
        containerColor = ...
    )
}

@Composable
fun ComposableSettingTheme() {
    val singleDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable(onClick = {
            singleDialog.value = true
        })) {
        Text(text = "Theme")
        Text(text = selectedOption) // selected theme name should be appearing here

        if (singleDialog.value) {
            AlertSingleChoiceView(state = singleDialog)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CommonDialog(
    title: String?,
    state: MutableState<Boolean>,
    content: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            state.value = false
        },
        title = title?.let {
            {
                Column( Modifier.fillMaxWidth() ) {
                    Text(text = title)
                }
            }
        },
        text = content,
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = { state.value = false }) { Text("OK") }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = { state.value = false }) { Text("Cancel") }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun AlertSingleChoiceView(state: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    CommonDialog(title = "Theme", state = state) { SingleChoiceView(state = state) }
}

@Composable
fun SingleChoiceView(state: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    val radioOptions = listOf("Day", "Night", "System default")
    val (selectedOption, onOptionSelected) = remember { mutableStateOf(radioOptions[2]) }
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        radioOptions.forEach { themeOption ->
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .clickable(onClick = { })
                    .selectable(
                        selected = (text == selectedOption),
                        onClick = {onOptionSelected(text)}
                    )
    ) {
                RadioButton(
                    selected = (text == selectedOption),
                    onClick = { onOptionSelected(text) }
                )
                Text(text = themeOption)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official documentation, you should use [state hoisting pattern](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting).

Thus:

1. Just take out `selectedOption` local variable to the "highest point of it's usage" (you use it in `SingleChoiceView` and `ComposableSettingTheme` methods) - `ScreenSettings` method.
2. Then, add `selectedOption: String` and `onSelectedOptionChange: (String) -> Unit` parameters to `SingleChoiceView` and `ComposableSettingTheme` (You can get more info in documentation).
3. Refactor your code using this new parameters:

   - Pass `selectedOption` local variable from `ScreenSettings`
     into `SingleChoiceView` and `ComposableSettingTheme`.
   - Write logic of `onSelectedOptionChange` - change local variable to new passed value

Hope I helped you!

Comment: For step 1, would the `selectedOption` local variable be placed between the `ScreenSettings` and `ComposableSettingTheme` functions?

Comment: No, it should be moved into the body of ```ScreenSettings``` method